# Posting JSON data to API using CURL

Tags: php, json, api, curl

When I'm posting `json` data to API using `curl` - I'm not getting any output. I would like to send email invitation to recipient.

```
$url_send ="http://api.address.com/SendInvitation?";
$str_data = json_encode($data);

function sendPostData ($url, $post) {

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

And here is `JSON` `$str_data`

```
[
    {
        "authorizedKey"  : "abbad35c5c01-xxxx-xxx",
        "senderEmail"    : "myemail@yahoo.com",
        "recipientEmail" : "jaketalledo86@yahoo.com",
        "comment"        : "Invitation",
        "forceDebitCard" : "false"
    }
]
```

And calling function:

```
$response = sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);
```

This is the API: https://api.payquicker.com/Help/Api/POST-api-SendInvitation

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`
And changing `http_build_query($post)` to `$post`

The implementation:

```
<?php

$data = array(
  "authorizedKey" => "abbad35c5c01-xxxx-xxx",
  "senderEmail" => "myemail@yahoo.com",
  "recipientEmail" => "jaketalledo86@yahoo.com",
  "comment" => "Invitation",
  "forceDebitCard" => "false"
);

$url_send ="http://api.payquicker.com/api/SendInvitation?authorizedKey=xxxxx";
$str_data = json_encode($data);

function sendPostData($url, $post){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
  return $result;
}

echo " " . sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);

?>
```

The response I get is:

```
{"success":false,"errorMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","status":"N/A"}
```

But maybe it will work with valid data....

**Edit:**
For posting xml,
it's the same as on their site, except in a string:

```
$xml = '
<SendInvitationRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PQApi.Models">
  <authorizedKey>80c587b9-caa9-4e56-8750-a34b17dba0a2</authorizedKey>
  <comment>sample string 4</comment>
  <forceDebitCard>true</forceDebitCard>
  <recipientEmail>sample string 3</recipientEmail>
  <senderEmail>sample string 2</senderEmail>
</SendInvitationRequest>';
```

Then:

```
sendPostData($url_send, $xml)
```

Comment: I just read on their api "_please append that to the url with ?authorizedKey=xxxxx_", I'll change the code above too

Comment: do i need to assign that xxxx with my authentication key ??

Comment: im still getting the {"success":false,"errorMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","status":"N/A"}

Comment: i try to contact there support it staff as im still getting that error anyway thanks a lot for taking time to my question

Comment: Hope it works out for you! -I was thinking of trying to use xml instead of json, cause I tried one of their other api calls using xml and it worked.

Comment: how do i call simplexml_load_file('data.xml') in sendPostData?

Comment: You don't need to. You should be able to send the xml as a string. However, I tried it with no success. It would be nice to know what they mean with the error message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` ...

Comment: can you post the code xml format and I try if its work.. thanks a lot

Comment: thanks a lot. I think this response from there server is something to do with.. System.Net.Mail on EXCHANGE Server.

Answer (score 13):

You have to add header:

```
$headers= array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json');
```

And:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Otherwise ...

> HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

... may happen.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to add headers as you already do `json_encode`. 
just `print_r (curl_getinfo($ch));` and see the content type info in it.